# id value in blade.html different from its value in database

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I found in my Laravel project that the id value for my entry is different from its real value in the database.

example:

#### Database

##### Entry 1

- id: 2
- name: John
- job: driver

##### Entry 2

- id: 3
- name: Sara
- Job: Nurse

In the blade file, it will give me this:

##### Entry 1

- id: 1
- name: John
- job: driver

##### Entry 2

- id: 2
- name: Sara
- job: Nurse

This is my controller:

```php
public function sponsorship_transfer(Request $request)
{
    $data['q'] = $request->query('q');
    $data['profession_id'] = $request->query('profession_id');
    $data['nationality_id'] = $request->query('nationality_id');
    $data['professions'] = WorkerProfession::all();
    $data['nationalities'] = WorkerNationality::all();

    $query = InWorker::select('in_workers.*', 'worker_statuses.*', 'worker_nationalities.*', 'worker_professions.*')
        ->join('worker_statuses', 'worker_statuses.id', '=', 'in_workers.status_id')
        ->join('worker_nationalities', 'worker_nationalities.id', '=', 'in_workers.nationality_id')
        ->join('worker_professions', 'worker_professions.id', '=', 'in_workers.profession_id')
        ->with(['languages', 'education', 'experience', 'birthday_place', 'media'])
        ->where('status_id', 3)->where(function ($query) use ($data) {
            $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $data['q'] . '%');
        });

    if ($data['profession_id'])
        $query->where('worker_professions.id', $data['profession_id']);

    if ($data['nationality_id'])
        $query->where('worker_nationalities.id', $data['nationality_id']);


    $data['in_workers'] = $query->get();

    return view('frontend.sponsorship_transfer', $data);
}
```

And this is my blade code:

```html
@foreach ($in_workers as $inWorker)
    <div class="invest-title-tow">
        <h3>{{ $inWorker->id }}</h3>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I tried changing the blade to be like this, but nothing happened:

```html
@foreach ($in_workers as $inWorker)
    <div class="invest-title-tow">
        <h3>{{ $inWorker->ID }}</h3>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Could you help me to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Although, I am not familiar with `->join()` concept, but I think issue may be on merge of Id's of all the tables like: `in_workers.id`, `worker_statuses.id`, `worker_nationalities.id`, `worker_professions.id`.

Comment: The issue is clearly the `join`, as @JSTECH stated... Why are you joining data instead of using [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships)? If you had relationships, you would only need to eager load them as you are doing with the `with` method call. And one recommendation, stick to [`PSR`](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#51-if-elseif-else), total discourage the use of `if (expression) result`, use `{ }`

Comment: I used join because I'm using advance filter to filter my data

Comment: It may be getting confused as to which `id` column you are referring to.  When you use select this way, it flattens the model and subsequent id columns will eclipse the earlier ones. I suspect you are seeing `worker_professions.id`.

Comment: try this: `$query = InWorker::select('in_workers.id as inWorkerId','in_workers.*', ...` And in your blade, use `<h3>{{ $inWorker->InWorkerId }}</h3>`

Comment: Of course, I totally agree with @matiaslauriti, you should be using relationships. It makes the code far more readable and updatable. You can still use filters with relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by this

```
public function sponsorship_transfer(Request $request)

{




    $data['q'] = $request->query('q');
    $data['profession_id'] = $request->query('profession_id');
    $data['nationality_id'] = $request->query('nationality_id');
    $data['professions'] = WorkerProfession::all();
    $data['nationalities'] = WorkerNationality::all();




    $query = InWorker::with(['status', 'nationality', 'profession', 'languages', 'education', 'experience', 'birthday_place', 'media'])
        ->where('status_id', 3)->where(function ($query) use ($data) {
            $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $data['q'] . '%');
        });

    if ($data['profession_id'])
        $query->where('profession_id', $data['profession_id']);

    if ($data['nationality_id'])
        $query->where('nationality_id', $data['nationality_id']);


    $data['in_workers'] = $query->paginate(9);
    return view('frontend.sponsorship_transfer', $data );
}
```